# Firestore document not getting created

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a Firestore document consisting of a document whose keys are Web URLs and the values are a collection of documents. I specify the document reference using the URL and the user ID, as follows:

```
private String replaceSlashSeparators(String url) {
    return url.substring(0, 8) + url.substring(8).replaceAll("/", "%2F");
}

private void postComment(String page_url, String userID, String subj, String msg) {
    DocumentReference mLinkDocRef = db.collection("links").document(replaceSlashSeparators(page_url)).collection("comments").document(userID);
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put(FSNAME, mUsername);
    data.put(FSIMGURL, mPhotoUrl);
    data.put(FSDEVICEID, deviceID);
    data.put(FSSUBJECT, subj);
    data.put(FSCOMMENT, msg);
    mLinkDocRef.set(data)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Listen failed.", task.getException());
                                    crashlytics.log("Listen failed." + Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage());
                                    return;
                                }
                                showCommentPostedDialog();
                            });
                    Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

I'm expecting to see a document in the "links" collection containing a URL and the "comments" document having the data described above, but instead no document is created. The set() calls onSuccess(), so the document should have been created. Anyone have an idea why this is happening? [image]

Comment: Is your `onSuccess` or `onFailure` even triggered?

Comment: Yes. onSuccess is triggered. That's the weird thing.

Comment: If you try to add some dummy data, does it work?

Comment: When I built the database, I created a dummy document called "initial" and made it point to the collection "comments", created a document in "comments" also named "initial" and just now created a field in the document.

Comment: Also, when onSuccess() was called, I verified that task.isSuccessful() was true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarassing. It turned out my code was correct. The reason the document didn't appear was because I had to refresh the collection. I never used to have to do that to get the document to appear, but I guess that when you have a longish hierarchy, it's necessary.